# Perl Command Output Using Pipe

Tags: perl

Can anyone tell me why this is not printing anything except the normal script output?

```
open( PS, "python /home/me/someprogram.py --option1 A -d somedomain.com |" ) || die "Failed: $!\n";
while (<PS>) {
    my $line = $_;
    print "LINE = $line\n";
}
```

In other words it never prints:

LINE = ...

Just the regular output as if I was running directly from command line.

Whereas the following works fine:

```
open( PS, "ps waux |" ) || die "Failed: $!\n";
while (<PS>) {
    my $line = $_;
    print "LINE = $line\n";
}
```

**EDIT (SOLVED)**

This works

```
open( PS, "python /home/me/someprogram.py --option1 A -d somedomain.com 2>&1 |" ) || die "Failed: $!\n";
while (<PS>) {
    my $line = $_;
    print "LINE = $line\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it - open( PS, "python /home/me/someprogram.py --option1 A -d somedomain.com 2>&1 |")

Comment: @mpapec Do you care to explain why combining stderr with stdout makes it work please? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell OP was capturing STDOUT, and as it seems python script outputs all useful content to STDERR.

Comment: How weird! Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
open( PS, '-|','python /home/me/someprogram.py --option1 A -d somedomain.com' )
```

Comment: Tried that also and it did not work. Now solved (above) using 2>&1.